# A question about Sylow's theorems and index of groups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I'm trying to prove this exercise:

Let be $G$ a finite group, p a prime number, and $H$ a normal subgroup. If $p \nmid [G:H]$, then $\{ x \in G : o(x)=p^{n_x}, \text{ with } n_x \in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq H$.

I tried by contradiction. If $B=\{x \in G : o(x)=p^{n_x}, \text{ with } n_x \in \mathbb{N} \} \nsubseteq H$. Then, $\exists \; y \in B$ such that $y \notin H$ and $o(y)=p^{n_y}$. I take $\langle y \rangle \in Syl_p(n_y, G)$ and I tried to use Sylow's theorems but didn't get to much...

I think that $B$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup, but I can't prove this.

I appreciate any help you can give me.

I use the next:

$o(x):=$ order of $x$

Definition: Let be $G$ a finite group, $p \in \mathbb{N}$ a prime and $n \geq 1$ such that $p^n \mid |G|$ and $p^{n+1} \nmid |G|$. For every $r \in [1,n]$ define:

$a)$ $Syl_p(r, G)= \{H \leq G : |H|=p^r \}$.

$b)$ the set of Sylow p-subgroups  $Syl_p(G):=Syl_p(n, G)$.

Comment: In general, $B$ need not be a subgroup; for example, in $S_3$, the set $B$ corresponding to $p=2$ contains all transpositions and the identity, and this is not a subgroup. $B$ is the set-theoretic union of all Sylow $p$-subgroups, and unions of subgroups are not generally subgroups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why so complicated? If $x \in G$, then for $\overline{x} \in G/H$, we have $order(\overline{x}) \mid |G/H|$ and also $order(\overline{x}) \mid order(x)$. Hence, if $x$ is a $p$-element, $\overline{x}$ is a $p$-element, while $p \nmid |G:H|$, so $\overline{x}=\overline{1}$, that is $x \in H$.

Comment: Oh... I see, I was blinded by Sylow's theorems, because this exercise is in that section. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Heh; I didn't notice the "normal" until much later, so I was already going down the road of using Sylow... Of course it is false without the "normal", as $H$ of order $2$ in $S_3$ shows...

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. If $p$ does not divide $[G:H]$, then every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. (Why?)
2. If $y$ has order a power of $p$, then $\langle y\rangle$ is a $p$-subgroup, hence contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$. (Why?)
3. In particular, there is a conjugate of $y$ that is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$. (Why?)
4. But $H$ is normal, which implies that $y$ itself is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ (Why?)
5. Thus, $y\in H$.

Comment: I can't justify the steps 1 and 4, but I will try. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Mr.K: For 1: compare the largest power of $p$ that divides $|G|$ with the largest power of $p$ that divides $|H|$. For 4, if $gyg^{-1}\in P\leq H$, then $y\in g^{-1}Pg\leq g^{-1}Hg$.

Comment: ohh ok ok, Thanks for your help! :)